# Close button : empty cell condition

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code and it works perfectly. But when I hit close button, dialog is shown "Do you weant to save changes", and if I choose Yes, an error comes up that I don't have a value in a cell A. And then my file is automatically closed.

**How to prevent this, and to stay in the document?**

My code is:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
Response = MsgBox("Please enter a value in A1", vbCritical, "Error!")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using BeforeClose instead of BeforeSave?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
     Cancel = True
     Response = MsgBox("Please enter a value in A1", vbCritical, "Error!")
 End If
End Sub
```

Regards